# Powershell Script - AD Discovery - Get-CimInstance : Access is denied. - SCCM 2012

Tags: powershell, active-directory, sccm, discovery

I'm trying to create a powershell script to make AD Discovery possible, whenever i start te script i always get Get-CimInstance : Access is denied.
i also try to fill in the values of a Active Directory Container but the script always says that the property .Values cannot be found on this object.

what am i doing wrong ?

this is the full script:

```
    Import-Module 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminConsole\bin\ConfigurationManager'
Set-Location PS1:

# variable

$CMSiteCode = 'PS1'
$CMSiteServer = 'CM01.local.cursusdom.tm'
$CMNameSpace = "root\SMS\site_$CMSiteCode"

# create a schedule

$CMGroupDiscoverySchedule = New-CMSchedule -RecurInterval Days -RecurCount 7



# Forest Discovery

Set-CMDiscoveryMethod -ActiveDirectoryForestDiscovery ` -SiteCode $CMSiteCode ` -EnableActiveDirectorySiteBoundaryCreation $true ` -EnableSubnetBoundaryCreation $true `  -Enabled $true





# Configure Group Discovery


#  Create the base discovery method using the schedule

Set-CMDiscoveryMethod -ActiveDirectoryGroupDiscovery `  -SiteCode $CMSiteCode `  -EnableDeltaDiscovery $true ` -DeltaDiscoveryIntervalMinutes 5 `  -EnableFilteringExpiredLogon $true `  -TimeSinceLastLogonDays 30 `  -EnableFilteringExpiredPassword $true `  -TimeSinceLastPasswordUpdateDays 90 `  -PollingSchedule $CMGroupDiscoverySchedule `  -Enabled $true



#  AD containers
$ADGroupDiscovery = Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $CMSiteServer `
    -Namespace $CMNameSpace `
    -ClassName SMS_SCI_Component `
    -Filter 'ComponentName ="SMS_AD_SECURITY_GROUP_DISCOVERY_AGENT"'

$ADContainerProp = $GroupDiscovery.PropLists | where {$_.PropertyListName -eq "AD Containers" }
$ADContainerProp.Values = "Acme - Software groups",0,0,1  


$ADGroupDiscovery = Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $CMSiteServer `    -Namespace $CMNameSpace `    -ClassName SMS_SCI_Component `    -Filter 'ComponentName ="SMS_AD_SECURITY_GROUP_DISCOVERY_AGENT"'


$NewGroupProp = New-CimInstance -ClientOnly -Namespace $CMNameSpace -ClassName SMS_EmbeddedPropertyList -Property @{PropertyListName='Search Bases:PS1';Values=[string[]]'LDAP://OU=Software groups,OU=Acme,DC=Local,DC=cursusdom,DC=tm'}
$ADGroupDiscovery.PropLists += $NewGroupProp


# change back to the CIM instance
Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $CMSiteServer `    -Namespace $CMNameSpace `    -ClassName SMS_SCI_Component `    -Filter 'ComponentName ="SMS_AD_SECURITY_GROUP_DISCOVERY_AGENT"' | Set-CimInstance -Property @{PropLists=$ADGroupDiscovery.PropLists}









# Configure System Discovery

# polling schedule

$CMSystemDiscoverySchedule = New-CMSchedule -RecurInterval Days -RecurCount 1

# Create the base discovery method using the schedule

Set-CMDiscoveryMethod -ActiveDirectorySystemDiscovery `  -SiteCode $CMSiteCode `  -EnableDeltaDiscovery $true `  -DeltaDiscoveryIntervalMinutes 5 `  -EnableFilteringExpiredLogon $true `  -TimeSinceLastLogonDays 30 `  -EnableFilteringExpiredPassword $true `  -TimeSinceLastPasswordUpdateDays 90 `  -PollingSchedule $CMSystemDiscoverySchedule `  -Enabled $true


# AD containers

$ADSysDiscovery = Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $CMSiteServer `-Namespace $CMNameSpace `    -ClassName SMS_SCI_Component `    -Filter 'ComponentName ="SMS_AD_SYSTEM_DISCOVERY_AGENT"'

$ADContainerProp =$Sysdiscovery.PropLists | where {$_.PropertyListName -eq "AD Containers" }
$ADContainerProp.Values = "LDAP://OU=Domain Controllers,DC=local,DC=cursusdom,DC=tm",1,1 # Ldap path of the Container, Recursive search, Discover objects within groups

$ADContainerProp =$Sysdiscovery.PropLists | where {$_.PropertyListName -eq "AD Containers" }
$ADContainerProp.Values = "LDAP://OU=Computers,OU=Acme,DC=local,DC=cursusdom,DC=tm",1,1 # Ldap path of the Container, Recursive search, Discover objects within groups

# change back to the CIM instance

Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $CMSiteServer `
    -Namespace $CMNameSpace `
    -ClassName SMS_SCI_Component `
    -Filter 'ComponentName ="SMS_AD_SYSTEM_DISCOVERY_AGENT"' | Set-CimInstance -Property @{PropLists=$ADSysDiscovery.PropLists}





# User Discovery

# polling schedule

$CMUserDiscoverySchedule = New-CMSchedule -RecurInterval Days -RecurCount 1

#  Create the base discovery method

Set-CMDiscoveryMethod -ActiveDirectoryUserDiscovery `
  -SiteCode $CMSiteCode `
  -EnableDeltaDiscovery $true `
  -DeltaDiscoveryIntervalMinutes 5 `
  -PollingSchedule $CMUserDiscoverySchedule `
  -enabled $true

# AD containers

$ADUserDiscovery = Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $CMSiteServer `
    -Namespace $CMNameSpace `
    -ClassName SMS_SCI_Component `
    -Filter 'ComponentName ="SMS_AD_USER_DISCOVERY_AGENT"'

$ADUserContainers = $ADUserDiscovery.PropLists | Where-Object {$_.PropertyListName -eq 'AD Containers'}

$ADContainerProp.Values = "LDAP://OU=Users,OU=Acme,DC=local,DC=cursusdom,DC=tm",0,0

$ADContainerProp.Values = "LDAP://OU=Admins,OU=Acme,DC=local,DC=cursusdom,DC=tm",0,0


# change back to the CIM instance

Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $CMSiteServer `
    -Namespace $CMNameSpace `
    -ClassName SMS_SCI_Component `
    -Filter 'ComponentName ="SMS_AD_USER_DISCOVERY_AGENT"' | Set-CimInstance -Property @{PropLists=$ADUserDiscovery.PropLists} 

# 5.0 - Restart SMS_SITE_COMPONENT_MANAGER Service to apply changes

Get-Service -ComputerName $CMSiteServer -Name SMS_SITE_COMPONENT_MANAGER | Restart-Service
```

these are the errors i'm getting:

```
PS C:\Users\Admin> C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\AD discovery.ps1
Get-CimInstance : Access is denied.
At C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\AD discovery.ps1:34 char:21
+ $ADGroupDiscovery = Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $CMSiteServer `
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Get-CimInstance], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070005,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.GetCimInstanceCommand
    + PSComputerName        : CM01.local.cursusdom.tm

The property 'Values' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\AD discovery.ps1:40 char:1
+ $ADContainerProp.Values = "Acme - Software groups",0,0,1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

Get-CimInstance : Access is denied.
At C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\AD discovery.ps1:43 char:21
+ ... Discovery = Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $CMSiteServer `    -Namespa ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Get-CimInstance], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070005,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.GetCimInstanceCommand
    + PSComputerName        : CM01.local.cursusdom.tm

The property 'PropLists' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\AD discovery.ps1:47 char:1
+ $ADGroupDiscovery.PropLists += $NewGroupProp
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

Get-CimInstance : Access is denied.
At C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\AD discovery.ps1:51 char:1
+ Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $CMSiteServer `    -Namespace $CMNameSp ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Get-CimInstance], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070005,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.GetCimInstanceCommand
    + PSComputerName        : CM01.local.cursusdom.tm

Get-CimInstance : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '-Namespace'.
At C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\AD discovery.ps1:74 char:19
+ ... Discovery = Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $CMSiteServer `-Namespace $ ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-CimInstance], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.GetCimInstan 
   ceCommand

The property 'Values' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\AD discovery.ps1:77 char:1
+ $ADContainerProp.Values = "LDAP://OU=Domain Controllers,DC=local,DC=c ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

The property 'Values' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\AD discovery.ps1:80 char:1
+ $ADContainerProp.Values = "LDAP://OU=Computers,OU=Acme,DC=local,DC=cu ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

Get-CimInstance : Access is denied.
At C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\AD discovery.ps1:84 char:1
+ Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $CMSiteServer `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Get-CimInstance], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070005,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.GetCimInstanceCommand
    + PSComputerName        : CM01.local.cursusdom.tm

Get-CimInstance : Access is denied.
At C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\AD discovery.ps1:110 char:20
+ $ADUserDiscovery = Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $CMSiteServer `
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Get-CimInstance], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070005,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.GetCimInstanceCommand
    + PSComputerName        : CM01.local.cursusdom.tm

The property 'Values' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\AD discovery.ps1:117 char:1
+ $ADContainerProp.Values = "LDAP://OU=Users,OU=Acme,DC=local,DC=cursus ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

The property 'Values' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\AD discovery.ps1:119 char:1
+ $ADContainerProp.Values = "LDAP://OU=Admins,OU=Acme,DC=local,DC=cursu ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

Get-CimInstance : Access is denied.
At C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\AD discovery.ps1:124 char:1
+ Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $CMSiteServer `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Get-CimInstance], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070005,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.GetCimInstanceCommand
    + PSComputerName        : CM01.local.cursusdom.tm

Restart-Service : Service 'SMS_SITE_COMPONENT_MANAGER (SMS_SITE_COMPONENT_MANAGER)' cannot be stopped due to the follo
wing error: Cannot open SMS_SITE_COMPONENT_MANAGER service on computer 'CM01.local.cursusdom.tm'.
At C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\AD discovery.ps1:131 char:76
+ ... Name $CMSiteServer -Name SMS_SITE_COMPONENT_MANAGER | Restart-Service
+                                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Restart-Servic 
   e], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStopService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RestartServiceCommand


PS PS1:\>
```

Could anyone help me ? :) i'm still trying to learn powershell.

thanks

Comment: Even you are apparently an `admin`, did you start PowerShell as an administrator (passing UAC)?

Comment: when i start as administrator i dont get the " Access is Denied" error anymore.

Now its just the "The property 'Values' cannot be found on this object." error i can't fix =/ 

do you know why it doesnt know the .values option? :)

Comment: Probably because `$GroupDiscovery.PropLists | where {$_.PropertyListName -eq "AD Containers" }` doesn't return any objects.